# ¿Alguna Estrategia en Mente?

Tags: javascript, html, css, algoritmos, svg

[image: Tablero del Juego]

La siguiente imagen es de un tablero de un juego que estoy preparando
El juego consiste en lo siguiente:
**2 Jugadores**
Los cuales tiene que ir marcando cada línea que tiene en el tablero hasta formar el cuadrado de los que están marcados una vez completado el cuadrado suma 1 punto y el cuadrado se marca con X(jugador 1) o O(jugador 2) (vale aclarar que aunque halla marcado 3 líneas un jugador si el otro jugador marca la ultima línea se lleva el punto del cuadrado)

**Ahora el Meollo del Asunto**
**DIVS**
al usar una estrategia de hacer el tablero con divs

```
<div id="filas">
    <div id="bordeSup"></div>
    <div id="bordeDer"></div>
    <div id="bordeInf"></div>
    <div id="bordeIzq"></div>
</div>
```

el problema esta en que en los limites de los cuadrados voy a tener duplicados algunos bordes

**SVG**

al trabajar el diseño con SVG me resulto mas cómodo pero un problema similar como detectar cuando un cuadrado se completa por ejemplo en la fila 0 cuadro 0 ese cuadrado va tener 3 bordes el superior, el izquierdo y el derecho .... pero como detectar el inferior .... y peor aun como hacerlo con los elementos de mas abajo

Comment: En caso de los bordes haz una condición en la cual solo debe de haber 3 líneas

Comment: el problema es que con 3 lineas no se completa el cuadrado entonces si pongo eso al tener las 3 seleccionadas se va marcar cuando esta faltando el borde inferior .. el cual pertenece al cuadrado de abajo en cuyo caso es su borde superior

Comment: El juego se llama `Timbiriche` en español y `Dots & Boxes`  en inglés. San google que todo lo sabe encontró este [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/dbuzinski/pen/JZrZbJ) que puede servirte como base.

Comment: ehhhhh genial ni siquiera yo sabia como se llamaba hace poco aburrido un amigo saco un papel y una hoja y me hizo jugarlo y decidí programarlo .. obviamente ni el sabia como se llamaba jajaja

Comment: Por favor edita y agrega que llevas al momento, lee [ask]